# Nginx proxy rewrite configuration

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxy, url-rewriting

it is possible to rewrite a url and use a proxy server for backgound connection?

An example, I want to use this URL `my.domain.org/demo` on my proxy server and redirect this into the root directory of my tomcat on another server with proxy_pass `my.tomcat.local`.

The url must be place `my.domain.org/demo` and must used the proxy url `my.tomcat.local` (without any subdomains).
Is this hook possible?

Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is absolutely possible.

Use the following configuration

```
location /demo {
    proxy_pass http://my.tomcat.local/; #Pay attention to the trailing slash. It MUST be present here.
}
```

The point is that if the specified proxy_pass destination contains path (a single slash is also considered as a path), then Nginx will directly pass request to that URL; otherwise, Nginx will append the path of the received URL to the proxy_pass destination and use the resulting URL.

Reference: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass

Comment: Thanks, with this configuration it will be works.
I had configured this before with an upstream, like this...
`upstream demo  {
 server 172.16.14.37:8081 fail_timeout=0;
}
location /demo {
 proxy_pass http://demo;
}
` ... but this doesnt work. Why?